# Server's file descriptor crashing after a client execute close()

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm having a problem with closing a socket.

I have a server that can accept n clients, but when one of them finishes the server's socket throws "bad file descriptor". I have the same algorithm in another server and there is no problem, I can't guess where is the problem, help!

Here is some code. Note that the server doesn't put the new clients in the watch of the select, just put them in another list.

The line that puts sockets in the master set shouldn't be there (the one after a new client connects).

Server

```
void planificador(t_scheduler_queue *scheduler_queue)
{

  int j, len, rc, on = 1;
  int listen_sd, max_sd, new_sd;
  int desc_ready, end_server = FALSE;
  int close_conn;
  char buffer[MAXSIZE];
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  struct timeval timeout;
  fd_set master_set;
  fd_set working_set;

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Create an AF_INET stream socket to receive incoming */
  /* connections on */
  /*************************************************************/
  listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (listen_sd < 0)
  {
    perror("socket() failed");
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Allow socket descriptor to be reuseable */
  /*************************************************************/
  rc = setsockopt(listen_sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *) &on,
      sizeof(on));
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    perror("setsockopt() failed");
    close(listen_sd);
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Set socket to be non-blocking. All of the sockets for */
  /* the incoming connections will also be non-blocking since */
  /* they will inherit that state from the listening socket. */
  /*************************************************************/
  rc = ioctl(listen_sd, FIONBIO, (char *) &on);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    perror("ioctl() failed");
    close(listen_sd);
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Bind the socket */
  /*************************************************************/
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  addr.sin_port = htons(scheduler_queue->portInt);
  rc = bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    perror("bind() failed");
    close(listen_sd);
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Set the listen back log */
  /*************************************************************/
  rc = listen(listen_sd, 32);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    perror("listen() failed");
    close(listen_sd);
    exit(-1);
  }

  /*************************************************************/
  /* Initialize the master fd_set */
  /*************************************************************/
  FD_ZERO(&master_set);
  max_sd = listen_sd;
  FD_SET(listen_sd, &master_set);

  do
  {
    /**********************************************************/
    /* Copy the master fd_set over to the working fd_set. */
    /**********************************************************/
    memcpy(&working_set, &master_set, sizeof(master_set));

    /**********************************************************/
    /* Call select() and wait 5 minutes for it to complete. */
    /**********************************************************/
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    rc = select(FD_SETSIZE, &working_set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    /**********************************************************/
    /* Check to see if the select call failed. */
    /**********************************************************/
    if (rc < 0)
    {
      perror(" select() failed");
      break;
    }

    /**********************************************************/
    /* Check to see if the 5 minute time out expired. */
    /**********************************************************/
    if (rc == 0)
    {
      planificar(scheduler_queue);
    }
    else
    {
      desc_ready = rc;
      for (j = 0; j <= max_sd && desc_ready > 0; ++j)
      {
        /*******************************************************/
        /* Check to see if this descriptor is ready */
        /*******************************************************/
        if (FD_ISSET(j, &working_set))
        {
          /****************************************************/
          /* A descriptor was found that was readable - one */
          /* less has to be looked for. This is being done */
          /* so that we can stop looking at the working set */
          /* once we have found all of the descriptors that */
          /* were ready. */
          /****************************************************/
          desc_ready -= 1;

          /****************************************************/
          /* Check to see if this is the listening socket */
          /****************************************************/
          if (j == listen_sd)
          {
            printf(" Listening socket is readable\n");
            /*************************************************/
            /* Accept all incoming connections that are */
            /* queued up on the listening socket before we */
            /* loop back and call select again. */
            /*************************************************/
            do
            {
              /**********************************************/
              /* Accept each incoming connection. If */
              /* accept fails with EWOULDBLOCK, then we */
              /* have accepted all of them. Any other */
              /* failure on accept will cause us to end the */
              /* server. */
              /**********************************************/
              new_sd = accept(listen_sd, NULL, NULL);
              if (new_sd < 0)
              {
                if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                  perror(" accept() failed");
                  end_server = TRUE;
                }
                break;
              }

              /**********************************************/
              /* Add the new incoming connection to the */
              /* master read set */
              /**********************************************/
              printf(" New incoming connection - %d\n", new_sd);
              FD_SET(new_sd, &master_set);
              queue_push(scheduler_queue->character_queue, new_sd);
              if (new_sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = new_sd;

              /**********************************************/
              /* Loop back up and accept another incoming */
              /* connection */
              /**********************************************/
            } while (new_sd != -1);
          }

          /****************************************************/
          /* This is not the listening socket, therefore an */
          /* existing connection must be readable */
          /****************************************************/
        }
      } /* End of if (FD_ISSET(i, &working_set)) */
    } /* End of loop through selectable descriptors */

  } while (end_server == FALSE);

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: first indent your code

Comment: Don't call `select` with `FD_SETSIZE` as first argument. Especially since you have the max file descriptor in `max_sd`. You should also check and update it when you close sockets.

Comment: Also, you do remember to remove closed sockets from the `master_set`?

Comment: Oh my! I didn't realize I was putting the new fd in the set, I don't want that, I guess that's my problem! I was going crazy. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, I'll leave a comment as soon as I finish with the test.

Comment: `if (new_sd < 0) { if (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) ...` There should _at least_ be a continue after the EWOULDBLOCK. Also: I can see no point where the accepted fds are handled (they are on the maseterset, which is copied to the working set at the beginning of the select() loop. )

Comment: No guys, the problem wasn't solve, that line that puts sockets in the master set shouldn't be there.

Comment: When appears the error message ?